# How to set Custom layout as Main View in setContentView in android

Tags: android, layout, view

I am having a custom layout named as sample.xml as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/Constituency" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="3dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:text="@string/Nampally" />         
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the MainActivity, the setContentView is set to

```
setContentView(R.Layout.activity_main)
```

which is the default xml file. Now I want to set the content view to sample.xml when my application starts.

I have given as

```
setContentView(R.Layout.sample);
```

when I ran my application, it says Unfortunately application has failed!! error.

When I debug, It show some nullpointer exception

This is my logcat,

```
04-04 03:55:40.691: D/AndroidRuntime(2174): Shutting down VM
04-04 03:55:40.691: W/dalvikvm(2174): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.liveapp/com.example.liveapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at com.example.liveapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-04 03:55:40.711: E/AndroidRuntime(2174):     ... 11 more
```

and This my MainActivity.java,

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   public final android.content.Context Context = MainActivity.this;
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      final LinearLayout samplelayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.sample);
     setContentView(R.layout.samplelayout);
  }
 }
```

whats wrong with my code?

Please Help!!

Comment: Can you post the code(java code)? And the logs?

Comment: Theres No problem with yor xml ,it works fine for me. Post your code

Comment: Posted Logcat and my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a NullPointerException when you switch from one layout file to another, it is most likely that you are accessing a reference to a View object with findViewById that doesn't exist in the new layout.  findViewById is returning a null object, so the moment you call a method or access a public property of that object, you get the NPE.

Also, the sampleLayout variable is redundant.

```
  final LinearLayout samplelayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.sample);
 setContentView(R.layout.samplelayout);
```

should simply be

```
 setContentView(R.layout.sample);
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is the cause the NPE, but its definitely wrong. In your line

> final LinearLayout samplelayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.sample);

You are trying to get a reference to a LinearLayout as a view but you are passing it the id of file. Where findViewById() works with view ids, not layout ids. Remove this line.

You simply need to have.

> setContentView(R.layout.samplelayout);

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a reference to the `LinearLayout` before it is created. You have to set the content view first and after that try to find the view by id. The other problem as that the id is wrong. Try this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.samplelayout);
final LinearLayout samplelayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.your_layout_id);
```